# Instanton effects on condensates: (pseudo)scalars, (pseudo)vectors, tensor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, superconductivity, quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-model, cpt-symmetry

I have heard that the instanton effect in quark matter causes the di-quark condensate to be Lorentz scalar. As opposed to the Lorentz **scalar**, there are possibilities that the condensates are Lorentz **pseudoscalars**, Lorentz vectors, Lorentz **pseudovectors**, or Lorentz **tensors**. It could also possibly break the Lorentz symmetry.

So what is the physical intuition or math reasoning behind that instanton effect favor **Lorentz scalar**, but does not favor (pseudoscalars) that breaks parity $P$? How about other cases?

Comment: What do you understand by the "di-quark condensate"?

Comment: It could be $<qq>, <\bar{q}q>$ and there are issues of their quantum numbers,  such as spin $s$, angular momentum $L$, charge, color, parity, Lorentz [(pseudo)scalars, (pseudo)vectors, tensor], etc.

Comment: By di-quark condensate, usually people mean $<qq>$. People may call $<q¯q>$ as anti-quark-quark condensate.

Comment: You, of course, don't mean the realistic QCD quark condensate causing the SSB in the QCD, right?

Comment: $ <q¯q> \neq 0$ in chiral symmetry breaking.  $<qq> \neq 0$ in superconducting phase. I am talking about the superconducting phase.

Comment: But how this "di-quark condensate" can be the scalar? It is non-invariant by the construction.

Comment: Do you agree that meson is $q¯q$ pair but it can be a pseudo-scalar? In fact, it can be (Pseudo)-scalar/vector meson and Tensor meson. If so what leaves the constraints for writing $qq$, and  for writing $q¯q$?

Comment: My understanding is that you can insert $\gamma^5$ and $\gamma^\mu$ into the condensate (what it means implicitly in the condensate shorthand).

Comment: The condensate itself has nothing to do with the vector, tensor and scalar mesons.

Comment: No, that was not what I mean. The instanton may favor certain channels such that only certein (pseudo)scalars, (pseudo)vectors, tensor tend to condense. I am asking which and what instanton causes this effect, what do they favor others.